# OpenCV 2 binary conversion

Tags: opencv

I want to convert a Mat of type Mono16 to a binary image, based on some threshold value for the pixels. I tried to use the following:

threshold(img, ret, 0.1, 1, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

When trying to compile, I get a make error that says:

error: ‘threshold’ cannot be used as a function

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"xxxx cannot be used as a function" usually means you are using 'xxxx' as a variable in your code.

Do you have a variable called `threshold` in your code (I'm betting you do...)? Because the variable will then hide the function.

```
int threshold = 120;
threshold(....);     // sure to fail as it looks like you're trying to use
                     // a variable as a function.
```